# How could this file be stored in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have this excel file attached, I am wondering how I could store it in matlab such that I could refrence it as A.AX, B.BY etc. What is the fastest way to do this. Or could I convert the excel file to a matlab file?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you already accepted, but here is another option

```
data = xlsread('Book1.xlsx');

a = data(:,1:4) ;
b = data(:,6:9) ;
c = data(:,11:14) ;

A = cell2struct( num2cell(a, 1) , {'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'}, 2);
B = cell2struct( num2cell(b, 1) , {'BW', 'BX', 'BY', 'BZ'}, 2);
C = cell2struct( num2cell(c, 1) , {'CW', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ'}, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am quite new to this, but this is what I get: "Undefined function or variable 'xlsreadata'."

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be `xlsread`. I renamed `data` using a replace all and didn't notice the error

Comment: Very good answer! It stores the data directly without typing directly. However, The Book1.xlsx must be stored in the MATLAB folder

Comment: You can change the file name to either the relative or exact path + the file name

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to import each column in row 3 of your doc as a matrix and then format them into tables named(A, B, C...)
For example:

```
AW = [148;174;177;217;280;145;291]; % Entries in column AW
AX = [376;360;553;390;464;359;411]; % Entries in column AX
A = table(AW,AX); % AW and AX are put into table named A
```

You can then easily acces each value or column by for example A.AW(1) or A.AW(:) etc.

The final table looks like this:

[image: Final table looks like this]